# Why are two identical external monitors displaying at different resolutions?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, resolution, displayport

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, Md 2012) running OS X El Capitan 10.11.3.

I purchased 1x DisplayPort to VGA and 1x DisplayPort to DVI.

I plugged these two into the 2x DisplayPorts on the MacBook Retina.

When I view the screens, however, one of them shows up fine but the other is at a low resolution (800x600).

I've seen some related posts, but nothing addressing this situation specifically. Most seem to be dealing with daisy chaining two external displays off of a single DisplayPort, but this MacBook Pro has two ports, so no daisy chaining.

Any thoughts on why the two different resolutions?

Comment: Why not use the built-in HDMI port alongside the DisplayPort-to-DVI adapter?

Comment: @jcaron - I think that is what I'm going to do, just wanted to see if there was any way to get current config working.

Comment: VGA is a very, very old standard, and should only be used for backwards compatibility (connect an old VGA-only monitor to a computer, or connect a VGA-only computer to a monitor). If both devices support DVI or HDMI, you should definitely go for those.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's in the DisplayPort to VGA not supporting a high enough resolution–although 800x600 is rather low, [there's not a hard rule for VGA.](https://superuser.com/questions/527192/what-maximal-resolution-is-reasonable-when-using-a-vga-cable) Have you tried switching which monitor uses VGA and seen if the resolution tracks?